# JAXB unmarshalling Unknown issue

Tags: java, xml-serialization, jaxb

I am unmarshalling a xml using JAXB , But it is returning wrong value all of a sudden it is returning a wrong value. A day before it was working fine.

Node :
`<ListID>166</ListID>`

The Unmarshalling code is :

```
public class ResponseParser {
static Object obj;

public static Object parseResponse(String response, Class<?> ctxClass) {
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance (ctxClass);
        Unmarshaller  unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        obj =   unmarshaller.unmarshal(input);
    }
    catch (JAXBException e) {

    }
    return obj;
}
}
```

It is returning : `-90` .But it is returning sequentially like before `-90` it was `-91`

Please Help!

Comment: Did you run your code through the debugger and made sure exactly what's getting passed into the unmarshaller?

Comment: So `response` is "<ListID>166</ListID>" and when you unmarshal this using JAXB you get -90 (or any other sequence number)? What type is `obj`? Maybe you could try with a concrete class instead of a generic wild card?

Comment: yes the response is "<ListID>166</ListID>" . obj is Object type .
It was working file and the application is ready but i dont know what happened all of a sudden .

Comment: @TusharAgarwal - I'm confused what does the input value `166` have to do with the outputs.  Why are you expecting `-90`?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan im am not epecting `-90` i need the value `116` that in node `<ListId>` but it is returning `-90` as such .

Comment: @TusharAgarwal - What is the value of ctxClass and what is the type of the returned object?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan - I have a bean class that i am passing as ctxClass and the object that is returned is casted to the same bean class.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan  : the xml that i am passing as response have other nodes also . The values of those nodes are correct , only the ListId that i am getting is wrong .

Comment: @TusharAgarwal - Could you tell me the type of field/property, what the corresponding get & set methods look like, and all annotations on that field/property.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan -  

`@XmlElement(name = "ListID")`
`protected byte listID;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input `166` is outside the range for `byte` which as a max value of `127` in Java.

```
package forum9632269;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
127
```

Comment: @TusharAgarwal - I have updated my answer based on the comments you added to your questions.  The issue is that the value `166` is outside the range of the `byte` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

It is very odd what you are facing, but **maybe** it has something to do with the xml file enconding. Try to replace the call

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes());
```

to

```
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getBytes("UTF8"));
```

Let us know if it is the real reason of your problem.